# ２本のRaycastを飛ばして交わった場所にオブジェクトを設置しようとしたが、rayが飛んでいく方向がおかしい

Tags: c#, unity3d, game-development

ワイヤーアクションのゲームを制作しようとしています。
分かりやすくするために下記のような名前を付けます。

rayC メインカメラから飛ばしたray
rayP プレイヤーから飛ばしたray

rayCをメインカメラから飛ばし,設置しているブロックに当たったら、プレイヤーからrayC.point(rayCとブロックが接触した座標)の方向にrayPを飛ばし,rayP.point(rayPとブロックが接触した座標)にオブジェクトを置きたいのですが、Debug.DrawRayを使ってみたとこrayCとrayPが予期しない方向に飛んでいきます。

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
　　　  //rayCを飛ばす
       Ray rayC = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
       RaycastHit hitC;
                
     //rayCが当たったら
     if (Physics.Raycast(rayC, out hitC, Mathf.Infinity))
     {
       Debug.Log($"HIT={hitC.collider.gameObject.name}");
       //当たったオブジェクトのタグがブロックだったら
       if (hitC.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("block"))
       {
          Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position,
          Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hitC.point) , UnityEngine.Color.green, 0.5f);
          Vector3 tempV = hitC.point;
          tempV.z = 0;

          //rayPを飛ばす
          Ray rayP = new Ray(player.transform.position, tempV);
          RaycastHit hitP;
          Debug.DrawRay(player.transform.position, tempV, UnityEngine.Color.red, 0.5f);

          //rayPがブロックと当たったら
          if (Physics.Raycast(rayP, out hitP, Mathf.Infinity))
          {
             Debug.Log($"ヒット"+hitP);
             GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
             Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos).y, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos).z);
             center.transform.position = new Vector3(hitP.point.x, hitP.point.y, hitP.point.z);
             Debug.Log($"hitプレイヤー"+ hitP.point);
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

いくつか間違いが見受けられます。

```cs
          Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position,
          Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hitC.point) , UnityEngine.Color.green, 0.5f);
```

[`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`は、スクリーン座標(マウスカーソルの位置など)からワールド座標に変換するもので、引数に渡すのはスクリーン座標です。
しかし、実際に渡しているのは当たった場所、つまりワールド座標です。
そもそももともとワールド座標なのだから、`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`を呼ぶ必要がないのでは？

[`Debug.DrawRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html)

更に、`Debug.DrawRay`の第2引数は、

> Direction and length of the ray.

と書かれているとおり、「レイの向かう位置」ではなく「レイの向きと長さ」です。
先の`Debug.DrawRay`の呼び出しも、同様の間違いをしているように見られます。

```cs
          Vector3 tempV = hitC.point;
          tempV.z = 0;

          //rayPを飛ばす
          Ray rayP = new Ray(player.transform.position, tempV);
```

[Ray Constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray-ctor.html)

`Ray`のコンストラクタに関しても同様、第2引数はレイの向きです。位置ではありません。

---

どうも間違いが多く、

- マニュアルをよく見ていない。
- 「位置ベクトル」と「方向ベクトル」の区別がついていない。

という感じがします。
前者であれば、マニュアルを読むクセをつけるべきですし、後者であれば、「位置ベクトル」「方向ベクトル」で検索すれば色々と説明してくれるサイトがあると思うので、しっかり理解してください。